# How to make OpenSessionInViewInterceptor work in Spring mvc

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, interceptor

I'm trying to set up OpenSessionInViewInterceptor in spring mvc to fix: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session.

Below is the code I already have and where the error comes from.

AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScans(value = { @ComponentScan("com.debugger.spring.web.tests"),  @ComponentScan("com.debugger.spring.web.service"), @ComponentScan("com.debugger.spring.web.dao"),
@ComponentScan("com.debugger.spring.web.controllers") })
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean getSessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

    Properties props = new Properties();

    // Setting JDBC properties
    ...

    // Setting Hibernate properties
    ...

    // Setting C3P0 properties
        ...

    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public OpenSessionInViewInterceptor openSessionInViewInterceptor() {
    OpenSessionInViewInterceptor openSessionInViewInterceptor = new OpenSessionInViewInterceptor();
    openSessionInViewInterceptor.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());
    return openSessionInViewInterceptor;
}
}
```

featured.jsp

```
<c:choose>
                            <c:when
                                test='${article.user.isSubscribed() and article.user.subscription.type eq "silver" }'>
                                <a class="bold"
                                    href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/u/${article.user.username}'><span
                                    class="silvername"> <c:out value="${article.user.name}"></c:out></span></a>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when
                                test='${article.user.isSubscribed() and article.user.subscription.type eq "gold" }'>
                                <a class="bold"
                                    href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/u/${article.user.username}'><span
                                    class="goldname"> <c:out value="${article.user.name}"></c:out></span></a>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:when
                                test='${article.user.isSubscribed() and article.user.subscription.type eq "premium" }'>
                                <a class="bold"
                                    href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/u/${article.user.username}'><span
                                    class="premiumname"> <c:out
                                            value="${article.user.name}"></c:out></span></a>
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <a class="bold"
                                    href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/u/${article.user.username}'><span>
                                        <c:out value="${article.user.name}"></c:out>
                                </span></a>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
```

${article.user.isSubscribed()} throws the error most likely because user cannot be fetched. I want it to run without using eager fetch and I think I can acheive it by setting up OpenSessionInViewInterceptor correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override [WebMvcConfigurer#addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#addInterceptors-org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry-) in your config class:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    OpenSessionInViewInterceptor openSessionInViewInterceptor = new OpenSessionInViewInterceptor();
    openSessionInViewInterceptor.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory().getObject());

    registry.addWebRequestInterceptor(openSessionInViewInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**");
}
```

Also add `@EnableWebMvc` on the config class.

*In response to OP's comment:*

I am not sure why it is not working. Everything seems fine to me. There is another way you can achieve this:

Set `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans` property `true`.

See [**23.9.1. Fetching properties** in Hibernate User Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-database-fetch) for more.

But this is *not* a very good option as stated in the guide:

> Although enabling this configuration can make
>   `LazyInitializationException` go away, it’s better to use a fetch plan
>   that guarantees that all properties are properly initialized before
>   the Session is closed.
>
> ```
> In reality, you shouldn’t probably enable this setting anyway.
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did as you suggested and instead of registry.addInterceptor I used registry.addWebRequestInterceptor because it says its not applicable. After running the revised application it still returns the same error as before (org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session).

Comment: @DisplayName Please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: I added the property to my db.properties but it still returns the same error.

Comment: @DisplayName I think you need to add this to `jpaPropertyMap` of `entityManagerFactory` or in `persistence.xml` See this link https://www.pavel.cool/jee-tips/LazyInitializationException-solution/. Again using `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans` is an anti-pattern. So, I would suggest you think again before using it! :)

Comment: Do you know of a better solution or of a way to minimize the negative effects of this anti-pattern?

Comment: @DisplayName Using `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` I think should be a better option here. But I myself is a little confused here. I will try to implement it and let you know if I get anything. :)